# XPath C# Attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

The following is the XML file read into XmlDocument

```
<Test xmlns="http://api.test.com/v2" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Result id="2015" description="Invalid Token" />
</Test >
```

What I need is the 'id' attribute value ("2015") stored in some TextBox

This is how XmlDocument is loaded

```
XmlDocument updateUser = new XmlDocument();
updateUser.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Works well till here.

Then, create namespace and search for node

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(updateUser.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("restup", "http://api.test.com/v2");

XmlNodeList locationElements1 = updateUser.SelectNodes("//restup:Test", nsmgr);
foreach (XmlNode Test in locationElements1)
{
//What DO I do here to get the value of 'id' attribute from the 'Result' node and save it in txtTest Textbox.

}
```

Comment: oh you posted xml. i'll change my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string idString = Test.FirstChild.Attributes["id"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var id = Test.FirstChild.Attributes["id"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

hello this is another method that can be useful

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileLocation); //fileLocation is the Path of the XML file
while (reader.Read())
{

  if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) //if the node is an element (not a comment, CDATA, or text)
     if (reader.Name == "Result")
       textBox1.Text = reader.GetAttribute("id");

}
reader.Close();
```

Comment: wlc. don't forget to vote up when your reputation reaches 15 points :P